# What does the $ar$ in $arcos(B)$ stand for?

Tags: trigonometry

Regarding to the Cosine formula solving with all sides and no angles?

$arcos(B)$ in the formula given  where is it derived?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_function#Etymology_of_the_arc-_prefix

Comment: It's actually an arc- prefix, but arccosine is awkward so we sometimes drop one of the c's.

Comment: @vadim123 I haven't seen arcos though, it's normally written $\arccos$ afaik.

Comment: ...trying to be diplomatic.

Comment: $$\;\; : - ) \;$$

Comment: Webster's 9th gives no hint of where the 'arc' as in $\arccos$ came from.

Comment: An interesting discussion of etymology is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33175/etymology-of-arccos-arcsin-arctan), including documentation of arcos and arsin in use (as well as others).

Answer (score 3):

You probably started with $b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos B$, rearranged that to $\cos B=\frac {a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}$ and then saw $B=\arccos(\frac {a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac})$  It is the inverse function to $\cos$, sometimes written $\cos^{-1}$.  It says $B$ is the angle whose cosine is $\frac {a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}$