# Domain of $\arccos(x)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, special-functions

Is there an explanation of why the domain of $\arccos(x)$ is $[-1, 1]$?

Comment: Because the range of $\cos$ is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Could you explain what does the range of cos have to do with the domain of arccos?

Comment: The domain of $\arccos$ is the range of $\cos$. The term 'arc' means inverse in this context. (See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33176/27978)

Comment: The idea behind $\arccos$ is that it takes an output of $\cos$ and sends it back to where it came from. So the possible inputs to $\arccos$ are just the possible outputs of $\cos$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is meant to be the inverse function to $\cos(x)$, which has a range of $[-1,1]$. The inverse $f^{-1}$ of a function $f$ has $f$'s codomain as its domain by definition; i.e., if $f: A \to B$ then $f^{-1} : B \to A$.